# Why should I add a header to a JWO?

Tags: jwt

I'm implementing a JWT in an API - Using Sinatra ruby on the server side and Vuejs on client side.

I understand why a JWT needs to be signed: because the signature contains the encoding of the payload and therefor is the payload is corrupted, the signature is invalid.

But what is the usage of the header?

Comment: *the signature contains the encoding of the payload* - the signature contains a hash value of header and payload

Answer (score 0):

From [documentation](https://jwt.io/introduction#Header):

> The header *typically* consists of two parts: the type of the token, which is JWT, and the signing algorithm being used, such as HMAC SHA256 or RSA.

So header contains information about JWT token algorithm and what type of token it is. Without that it would be hard to identify how to handle this token

Comment: Sorry, yes, but the header is encrypted itsself, so what use puting the signing algorithm in the header if you need to decrypt in order to access that information?

Comment: @thiebo the header is not encrypted, it's just base64url encoded. You can decode the header (and also payload) with any base64url decoder or on https://jwt.io or similar sites.